# R: Calculate predicted mean in a lm() function

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to compute the predicted/adjusted mean value of an outcome for a given simple linear regression model with both categorical and continuous variables. A quick example would be similar to the following.

```
dat <- data.frame(value = c(5,8,41,25,23,56,58,54,51,52,56,59),
                  x = c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "B","B","B", "B","B","G"),
                  y=c("C","C","C","D","D","D", "D","D","D", "D","E","E"), 
                  z = c(34,56,25,35,54,67,43,73,52,78,15,38))
m <- lm(value ~ x + y + z, dat)
```

How can I compute the adjusted mean value of the output given that x = "A", as well as the confidence interval of that value. Especially when there is another categorical variable in the model.

Thank you!!

Comment: `mean(dat[dat$x=="A","value"])` will give 26.33333 as the mean when `x` is `"A"`.  It is just the average of 5, 8, 41, 25, 23, 56

Comment: `predict(m, newdata, type= "confidence")`

Comment: Hi, guys, thank you all for the comments. I am sorry for not being very clear on my question. what I am trying to do is that for x, I will plug in the value"A", "B","C" separately (Since A will be the reference, it just means setting the dummy for B and C to be 0), while for all the other variables I want to plug in the mean value. It is easy for continuous variable, however, if it is a categorical variable, I wish to apply a ratio to represent the whole population. Therefore, in this case, I want the value of the dummy of "D" to be 7/12 instead of 1 or 0, and 2/12 for "E".

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thank you for the answer. I understand that predict.lm would give you the predicted value of the dependent variable for a given set of input values for the independent variables. However, I am wondering how would I input the value of a categorical independent variable. I guess one way to do it is to recreate the whole table 3*12, where x all equals to "A" (or "B" and "C" respectively), z all equal to the mean value, and maintain y as it is right now. Is there a quicker and more general way? I am trying to write a function that will handle these situations on different dataset.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all the help. I think lsmeans package is what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think package lsmeans solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for-

```
dat$predicted <- m$fitted.values
adj_mean <- aggregate(predicted ~ x, data = dat, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. However, I don't think this is what I intended to do. Since the distribution of y would not accurately represent the population, if that makes sense.